# VB.net Form unexpectingly terminating

Tags: vb.net, navigation, browser

Hi I have the following form but cant figureout why its upbrubtly terminiating when difrent buttons are clicked?

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub


Private Sub button1_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseEnter

    Dim TEST1 As Integer = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\test\test").Length
    If TEST1 = 0 Then

        Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.hotmail.com")

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub button1_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseLeave
    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://WWW.facebook.com")
End Sub

Private Sub button2_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseLeave
    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://WWW.facebook.com")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("file://C:\test\test")
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Button2.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("file://C:\test")
    Button2.Enabled = False
    Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub


Private Sub button2_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseEnter

    Dim TEST2 As Integer = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\test\test").Length
    If TEST2 = 0 Then

        Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.hotmail.com")

    End If

End Sub
```

The terms face book and hotmail are just random to keep company site private :)

Comment: are you getting some exception or error?

Comment: Nope no errors none in error list noproblems fiering up the debug hit button once all is okay hit button snd time and the debug just stops running

Comment: Try using Click instead of MoueseEnter event.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `Mouse_Enter` event and the `Mouse_Leave` events are not giving time to the webbrowser to fully load the document and maybe it is internally crashing.

Try checking if the webbrowser has finished working before navigating again and tell us:

Use

```
 If WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
      Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
 End if
```

Comment: Its having somwhat of an effect working half the time and half the time not. could it be that a mouse click is tringgering a mouseenter and the system is trying to clompleate two navigations simutainiously?

Comment: Did you added the code? Has the form stopped crashing?. If the form stopped crashing and you are experimenting something like the webbrowsert is not responding mouse enter and mouse leave events and it is not navigating all the time, maybe the problem is navigation concurrence

Comment: Yes I added the code but its only having a somwhat (random) effect IF I apply the code to every naviagtional change the whole form just displays a white webbrowser control, so the somewhat effect I am refering to is only is some of the navigate sequences have your code applyed